# POWERSHELL : split a string like awk

Tags: string, powershell

In a file i have many lines like this

```
Nom de l'objet :    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Device Stage\Task\{07deb856-fc6e-4fb9-8add-d8f2cf8722c9}\netfol.ico
```

I just want extension of the file (here ico). some extension may have more than 3 characters.
With awk, i can do, but in powershell...
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some regex:

```
$str = "Nom de l'objet :    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Device Stage\Task\{07deb856-fc6e-4fb9-8add-d8f2cf8722c9}\netfol.ico"
$str -match "\.(.{3,})$"
$extension = $Matches[1]
$extension #ico
```

`\.(.{3,})$` matches at least 3 chars after the last dot before the very end of the line.

Comment: What if the extension is less than 3 characters?

Comment: It wouldn't be matched at the moment @Bill_Stewart. But OP asked for: "some extension may have more than 3 characters", not less. ´\.(.+)$´ would match less or more.

Comment: The OP's statement should not be regarded as definitive IMO, since extensions can have 1 or more characters. [I'm quite familiar with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2102693+regex); I was pointing out that we should opt for the most robust solution possible.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use RegEx, why not use the [System.IO.Path] class to get the extension:

```
$str = "Nom de l'objet :    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Device Stage\Task\{07deb856-fc6e-4fb9-8add-d8f2cf8722c9}\netfol.ico"
$filename=($str -split ':',2)[1]
[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename)
```

Comment: I think there's some text before the filename?

Comment: Heh.  Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Nom de l'objet :    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Device Stage\Task\{07deb856-fc6e-4fb9-8add-d8f2cf8722c9}\netfol.ico"
if ( $str.LastIndexOf(".") -gt -1 ) {
    $str.Substring($str.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
}
# Outputs "ico"
```